# Migrate from Claim-based authentication to ADFS in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, claims-based-auth, adfs

Anybody tried migration from Claim-based authentication to ADFS successfully in SharePoint 2013 before...

How to handle to user account migration between claim-based and ADFS?

Comment: Do u want in new farm or within same farm, just changing authentication from claims to ADFS?

Comment: within the same farm

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMVP What are the procedures if I just want to change authentication from claims to ADFS for my existing production farm?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to accomplish this:

`Convert-SPWebApplication`. An example, including other information you may find helpful, is available on the KB article [The Convert-SPWebApplication command cannot convert from Windows claims to SAML in SharePoint Server 2013](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3042604/the-convert-spwebapplication-command-cannot-convert-from-windows-claims-to-saml-in-sharepoint-server-2013).

`Move-SPUser` is another option. The migration path would be like this:

```
$user = Get-SPUser -Identity 'i:0#.w|domain\jdoe' -Web https://siteUrl
Move-SPUser -Identity $user -NewAlias 'i:05.t|adfs|jdoe@domain.com' -IgnoreSid
```

Substitute the claim identifier, issuer, and identity appropriately.

Note that `Move-SPUser` is farm-wide.